# How to write sql query with variable in R?

Tags: r

I'm using dbGetQuery in R to fetch result.

```
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE invoice_date >= '2020-08-31 00:00:00.00000+00'")
```

I want to assign date to a variable and call it in query. Something like this,

```
invoice_date <- '2020-08-31 00:00:00.00000+00'
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE invoice_date >= {invoice_date}")
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: take a look at the paste() function

Comment: I tried this code ```paste("SELECT invoice_date,order_id, product_code, delivery_pincode,fulfilment_center FROM sales_report WHERE invoice_date >= ", invoice_date, "", sep="")``` but it is not taking as character with quotes

Comment: After @Waldi's response I tried this with paste option, it works. ```invoice_date <- "'2020-09-03 00:00:00.00000+00'"
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT invoice_date,order_id, product_code, delivery_pincode,fulfilment_center FROM sales_report WHERE invoice_date >= ", invoice_date, "", sep="")``` .Thanks !! But I'm accepting @Waldi's answer since it's more cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glue` package should perfectly fit your needs:

```
invoice_date <- '2020-08-31 00:00:00.00000+00'
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, glue::glue("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE invoice_date >= '{invoice_date}'"))
```

Another option is to include the quotes in the variable:

```
invoice_date <- "'2020-08-31 00:00:00.00000+00'"
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, glue::glue("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE invoice_date >= {invoice_date}"))
```

Comment: The assigned variable is not taking as character with quotes. I got this error  ```WHERE invoice_date >= 2020-09-04 00:00:00.00000+00 (ERROR: syntax error at or near "00"
  Position: 137)``` . Quotes are missing .

Comment: what if we have multiple where condition like --> where Material= "car" and invoice_date >= {invoice_date}

Comment: @Amit, you could build the where condition as needed, possibly with if statements, for example `mycondition <- "where "; mycondition <- paste(myconditon, " Material= 'car'"; mycondition <- paste(mycondition, glue("and invoice_date >= {invoice_date}")`